# How to extract a substring starting with a word from string

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I am writing a bash script and at some point I have
`$path="things useless things... path/another/files1/useful/path/here"`

So I am trying to remove all words and text before "files1" and get the part after files1 (included)

In this example: `files1/useful/path/here`

I was able to get the part after it but not including files1

How do  I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `${var#pattern}` syntax which will remove the shortest match of `pattern` from the front of the variable:

```
$ path="things useless things... path/another/files1/useful/path/here"
$ echo "${path#*another/}" 
files1/useful/path/here
```

Alternatively, you can use any standard text parsing tool. For instance:

```
$ newPath=$(sed -E 's|.*(files1/)|\1|'<<<"$path")
$ echo $newPath 
files1/useful/path/here
```

Comment: the another part is not constant, the files1 is constant though... I can use your solution and re-add the files1 manually, and this what I am currently doing in my script  but I was looking for a more elegant way...

Comment: @user206904 then please edit your question and clarify. Are you looking for something like `newPath=$(sed -E 's|.*(files1/)|\1|'<<<"$path")`?

Comment: Yes! that solves it!

Comment: @user206904 great, I added that to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

How about (for a file script):

```
sed -n 's#\(path="\).*/\(files1/[^"]*"\)#\1\2#p' script
```

Or, if the value is inside a variable:

```
$ path="things useless things... path/another/files1/useful/path/here"

$ echo "/files1/${path##*/files1/}"

/files1/useful/path/here
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using `bash` you may also use its builtin regex engine:

```bsh
$ path="things useless things... path/another/files1/useful/path/here"
$ [[ "$path" =~ /files1/.*$ ]] && echo "$BASH_REMATCH"
/files1/useful/path/here
```